# How can I import an __init__.py to write unit test for it?

Tags: python, import

This may be a very silly question, but I have an `__init__.py` packages with several functions inside, which I want to write unit tests for.

In my unit test file, I want to import this `__init__.py`, but it doesn't look right.

I would do:

```
from work.parser.bmpe.__init__ import some_function
```

Is the above ok?

Answer (score 2):

```
from work.parser.bmpe import some_function
```

should work.